# Swapping characters within a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Given a list of strings such as: `['Math is cool', 'eggs and bacon']`

How would one swap words from one list item to the other to turn them into something like

`['bacon is cool', 'eggs and Math']`

I would post code if I had any but I really have no idea where to start with this. Thanks.

I'm using Python 3

Comment: Do you have a scheme for swapping the words? ie. always swap the first word of the first string with the last word of the second string

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter the list item (ie 1-n) and word within that list that they want to swap with a corresponding list item and word. Thanks

Comment: And what version of Python are you using? (```2.x``` or ```3.x```)

Comment: I was able to strip out the words using string.strip but I couldn't figure out how to replace them in the proper position

Comment: @user2913067 Please post your code that attempts this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating your lists.

```
text1 = 'Math is cool'
text2 = 'eggs and bacon'
mylist = []
mylist.append(text1.split())
mylist.append(text2.split()

print mylist
```

Output:

```
[['Math', 'is', 'cool'], ['eggs', 'and', 'bacon']]
```

Now that you have the lists, play with them. Use append() to add texts that the user enters, etc.

I think that you can see where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing too much information as to your purpose in general (to say the least)... so the answer below refers only to the specific example given in your question, in order to help you get started:

```
list    = ['Math is cool', 'eggs and bacon']
list0   = list[0].split(' ')
list1   = list[1].split(' ')
newList = [list1[-1]+' '+' '.join(list0[1:]), ' '.join(list1[:-1])+' '+list0[0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

def swap_words(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1.split()    # split string into words
    s2 = s2.split()
    w1 = random.randrange(len(s1))    # decide which words to swap
    w2 = random.randrange(len(s2))
    s1[w1], s2[w2] = s2[w2], s1[w1]     # do swap
    return " ".join(s1), " ".join(s2)
```

then `swap_words('Math is cool', 'eggs and bacon')` returns sentences like

```
('Math and cool', 'eggs is bacon')
('bacon is cool', 'eggs and Math')
```

Comment: OP is asking for user input swap, not random

Comment: the important function calls are shown in this example